# Automatic update of application without user prompt Android

Tags: android

I have developed application to download apk file from web server and install it in android device programatically. But, I didn't find the way to do the same without user prompt dialog boxes. Can anyone help me in this issue?

Comment: Thank you Android.  This is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this is possible, because it will be a huge security hole otherwise. User downloads application that requires no permissions, and that applications downloads another malicious applications that steals all your data and rapes your cat. And you don't even know this.

Comment: That's not quite true; you can't change permissions without user prompting, thats correct. But if your app is eg. developed in MoSync, then theoretically, it should be possible to update the HTML5 LocalFiles folder afterwards, without any permission change (so you work with the same permissions as before). This is just a guess though.